# Query and Update Mongo Document

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, mongodb-query, spring-mongodb

The query below increases `score` by `one`.

```
db.people.findAndModify({
   query: { name: "Andy" },
   update: { $inc: { score: 1 } }
})
```

But, is it possible to do more than just increase the `score`. I would like to, increase the `score` and also compute `avg_field` for same document.

```
db.people.findAndModify({
   query: { name: "Andy" },
   update: { $inc: { score: 1 }, avg_field : {x divide by new score value} }
})
```

I might be able to use function to compute all that, but still that will not help inserting updated values. I would like to keep the operation atomic and hence trying to update in the same query.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could do it through [`aggregatioin`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/), with operator `$add` and `$divide` as below. However, the aggregation does not update the document, so you should return the cursor from aggregation, then update the document one by one. Here are the sample codes.

```
// increase score than compute the avg_field, then return the cursor.
var cur = db.people.aggregate([ 
    {$match: { name: "Andy" }},
    { "$project":
        { 
            "_id": "$_id", 
            "score": {$add: ['$score', 1]}, // add score by 1
            "avg_field": {$divide: ['$v1', {$add: ['$score', 1]}]} // compute the new avg_field
        } 
    }
]);

// Iterate through results and update each people.
cur.forEach(function(doc) {
    var doc = cur.next();
    db.people.update({ _id: doc._id },
                  { "$set": { avg_field: doc.avg_field, score: doc.score}});
});
```

Comment: Thats not a bad idea. I like it.